# Is injective the differential of $\varphi$?

Tags: differential-geometry

We consider $U = (- 1 , 1) \times (- 1 , 1)$ and $\varphi : U \to {\mathbb{R}}^3$ given by $\varphi (u , v) = (u^3 , v^3 , u v)$ for all $(u , v) \in U$. Is $d {\varphi}_p : {\mathbb{R}}^2 \to {\mathbb{R}}^3$ injective for all $p \in U$? Note: given $p \in U$, $d {\varphi}_p$ is the differential of $\varphi$ evaluated in $p$; for example, if we denote $x , y , z : U \to \mathbb{R}$ by $x(u , v) = u^3$, $y(u , v) = v^3$ and $z(u , v) = u v$ for all $(u , v) \in U$, then
$$
d {\varphi}_p = \left(
\begin{matrix}
\displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(p) & \displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}(p)
\\
\displaystyle \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}(p) & \displaystyle \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}(p)
\\
\displaystyle \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}(p) & \displaystyle \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}(p)
\end{matrix}
\right)\mbox{.}
$$
I think it is not injective because $d {\varphi}_0 = 0$. Then, calling $q_1 = (1 , 0)$ and $q_2 = (0 , 1)$, we have $q_1 \neq q_2$ and
$$
d {\varphi}_0(q_1) = \left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0
\\
0 & 0
\\
0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right) \left(
\begin{matrix}
1
\\
0
\end{matrix}
\right) = \left(
\begin{matrix}
0
\\
0
\\
0
\end{matrix}
\right) = \left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0
\\
0 & 0
\\
0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right) \left(
\begin{matrix}
0
\\
1
\end{matrix}
\right) = d {\varphi}_0(q_2)\mbox{.}
$$
What do you think? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote:

$$
d {\varphi}_p = \left(
\begin{matrix}
\displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(p) & \displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}(p)
\\
\displaystyle \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}(p) & \displaystyle \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}(p)
\\
\displaystyle \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}(p) & \displaystyle \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}(p)
\end{matrix}
\right)=\left(
\begin{matrix}
\displaystyle 3p_x^2 & 0
\\
\displaystyle 0& \displaystyle 3p_y^2
\\
\displaystyle p_y & \displaystyle p_x
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
Indeed choosing $p=(p_x,p_y)=(0,0)\ $ gives the zero matrix, which is clearly not injective.

But choosing either $p_x$ or $p_y$ non zero makes the matrix injective, as if $p_x\neq 0\neq p_y$ the top $2\times 2$ minor is non-zero, and if one of the coefficients is zero, the you can pick the non-zero rows, which form a non-zero diagonal matrix, thus of rank $2$.

Comment: Definitely, you think $d {\varphi}_p$ isn't injective, right?

Comment: at the origin it is **not** injective, yes. Everywhere else it is injective.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.